# Automatic Savetxt as CSV Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tkinter, geopandas

I am interested in clipping a dataset and after to autosave it following a name pattern(example: block1.csv, block2.csv....)
Right now I am doing it manually, my code is :

```
import csv 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point 

    
    
root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()
#--------------START---IMPORT-------------------
def getCSV ():
    global df
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = np.genfromtxt(import_file_path, delimiter='_', missing_values = ' ', filling_values = None)
    
    print (df)
    
browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text=" Import CSV File to clip ", command=getCSV, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=browseButton_CSV)

root.mainloop()


#--------------END---IMPORT------------------------------------

x, y, z, mag = df[:,0], df[:,1], df[:,2], df[:,3]


xmin, ymin = np.min(x), np.min(y)
xmax, ymax = np.max(x), np.max(y)
dtSeries = GeoSeries(map(Point, zip(x,y,z,mag)))


def clipping( x, y, z, mag, xc, yc):
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y, 'Z':z, 'MAG':mag})
    df1['geometry'] = list(zip(df1['X'], df1['Y'], df1['Z']))
    df1['geometry'] = df1['geometry'].apply(Point)
    gdfMAGN = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry='geometry')
    
    x1, y1 = xc, yc
    # ____________[90000m X 90000m] IS THE WINDOW DIMENSIONS______________
    
    clipAr = Polygon([ (x1, y1), (x1, y1+90000), (x1 + 90000, y1 + 90000), (x1+90000, y1)])
    pol = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[clipAr] )
    
    res = gpd.clip(gdfMAGN, pol)
    resCSV = np.array([res['X'],res['Y'],res['Z'],res['MAG']]).T
    
    
    #---------------------START---SAVE---------------------
    root= tk.Tk()

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
    canvas1.pack()

    def saveCSV ():
        global df
    
        export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename( defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[("CSV files", '*.csv')])
        np.savetxt(export_file_path, resCSV, delimiter='_')
    
    
    browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text="      Export filled CSV Data File     ", command=saveCSV, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_CSV)

    root.mainloop()
    #------------------------END---SAVE--------------------
    
xc, yc = np.min(x), np.min(y)

while True:
#---------45000m IS THE STEP -----------------------
    if xc = np.max(x):
        if yc = np.max(y):
            clipping(x, y, z, mag, xc, yc)
            break
        else:
            xc = xmin 
            yc = yc + 45000
    else:
        clipping(x, y, z, mag, xc, yc)
        xc = xc + 45000
```

Comment: i want to autosave the results with a name pattern as i said

Comment: probably you dont understand... I ASK if someone knows a way to autosave a csv. I DONT get any error because i do a manual save of my dataset {see the code i uploaded} using tkinter and numpy.savetxt. I dont have any code trying to autosave because i dont know how to do it

Answer (score -1):

In order to autosave results with a name that follows a pattern as i demonstrated, i added the following lines of code and removed the saveCSV(). I only kept the np.savetxt(....). With them, i get as an input a path from which i remove the last part and i get the file path.

```
 #-------------------START---------GET   PATH---------------------------
root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

def getPath ():
    global path
    
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename( defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("TXT files", '*.txt')])
    
    print(path)
        
    
browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text="      Set PATH     ", command=getPath, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_CSV)

root.mainloop()

#--------------------END-------GET   PATH---------------------------------------------

print(path)
strin = np.array([])
for i in path:
    strin=np.append(strin, i)
ind = np.where(strin=="/" )

j = str()
for i in path[0:(ind[0][len(ind[0])-1]+1)]:
    j += i
path  = j

print(path)
```

i added also in the clipping() 2 extra variables path and block and the following line of code to create a path and a name for each csv.

```
pathBlock = path + 'block' + str(bl) + '.csv'
np.savetxt(pathBlock, resCSV, delimiter='_')
```